# Roll, slip, or bounce?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, momentum, friction, collision

A sphere is dropped onto an infinite inclined plane. Can we predict whether the sphere rolls, slips, or bounces after hitting the surface?  If so, how can we predict this?

Comment: Need more specification.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking idealized conditions then it depends on whether the collision is elastic or inelastic. If it is at all elastic, bounce. If it is fully inelastic, and there is no gravity *or* no friction, slip. (There's no normal force, and so no friction that can spin the sphere up to rolling.) If there is gravity and friction, initially slip, then rolling once the friction spins the sphere up to where rotation matches translational motion.